# Clueless about how to use switch

Tags: if-statement, switch-statement, boolean, processing

this is my very first post :)

I'm a graphic design student in my second year and we have to make code for business cards.
What I want is when I click with my mouse the background of the business card will change.

It worked with a boolean for two pictures.
But now I want it to work with four images.

Have asked the teacher for help and she sent me information about Switch.

But I have no idea where to put in my code and how to fill it in.

This is my code so far

```
String Instagram="@Famoys_Saz";
String quote = "Guess my passion ;)";
PFont font;
PImage bg;
PImage Snake2;
PImage snake3;
PImage snake4;
boolean click = true; 



void setup() {
  size(850, 550);
  font = createFont("Galaxyfaceano-4yM9.ttf", 45);
  textFont(font);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  bg = loadImage("Snake.jpg");
  Snake2= loadImage ("Snake2.jpg");
  click = true;
}
void draw() {
  background(bg);
  if (click == true ) {
    image(bg, 0, 0);
  } else {  
    image(Snake2, 0, 0);
  }

  text(Instagram, mouseX, mouseY);
  text(quote, mouseY, mouseX, 05);
}

void mousePressed() {

  click =! click;
}
```

and this is the code my teacher send me:

```
if( imageNumber == 1 ) {
 
} else if ( imageNumber == 2 ) {
 
} else {

}
```

Could someone help me out? I'm quite a beginner when it comes to coding.

Comment: There are many examples online - just search **switch statement in C**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
switch(imageNumber) {
  case 1:
    // do stuff
    break;
  case 2:
    // do stuff
    break;
  case 3:
    // do stuff
    break;
  case 4:
    // do stuff
    break;
  default:
    // if no case was selected, do this
}
```

Switches are easy to read and efficient, and some programmers prefers them to `else if`. Both are fine, as long as they are readable, but the switch has some unique particularities, like having to use `break;` between cases. The `break;` will exit the switch, else it would evaluate every other possible case (thus you're saving some execution time).

It happened to me in a robotic project to deliberately skip the `break;` statement so the robot would do "everything from this point on", but it's very uncommon and a source of many beginner's bugs to forget the `break;`.

Depending on the language, switches can evaluate different things, but the classics are integers and strings.

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you for your comment :)

Comment: @SarahRose Hi Sarah! Please upvote the answers which helps you (you can upvote all of them if they all help), and when one answer solve your initial problem hit the checkmark to make it as the right answer to your situation (only one "official" answer per question). These actions will help future users with similar questions to find those informations, that's how this site works: we write answers for you, but also for future users at the same time! Have a nice day.

Comment: Thank you for explaining to me how this website works :)

Answer (score 1):

it will look something like this:

```
switch( imageNumber ) {
 
    case 1:  // same as saying imageNumber == 1
    //some code
    break;


    case 2:  // same as saying imageNumber == 2
    //some code here
    break;
}
```

Comment: I was just wondering what I need to fill in on the spot ImageNumber? Do I put there the name of the image?

Comment: you can use the image name. But i would recommend giving each image an ID and then passing that ID as integer to imageNumber and checking if it is 1,2,3,or 4 with case 1, case 2 and so on

Comment: Okay I think I know what to do now, Thank you for you help